# Use of article with "heavy traffic" vs. "a traffic jam"

Tags: articles

I would like to discuss the difference between the usage in these sentences below:

> I was delayed by a traffic jam.
>   I was delayed by heavy traffic.

The second one is correct, based on a TOEFL test sample. I also wonder why the sentence below is incorrect in the test:

> I was delayed by **a** heavy traffic

Both *traffic jam* and *heavy traffic* are objects. I know the preposition *a* must be put before *traffic jam* in this example, because the event is specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example you were delayed by *a jam*, that is *a hold-up* when the traffic either doesn't move or creeps forward. *Jam* is a countable noun. You can have multiple *jams* or *traffic jams*.

In the second example you were delayed by *traffic*, an uncountable noun. We don't use *a* or *an* ahead of uncountable nouns. They can stand alone or be used with the definite article *the*.

(The) traffic was heavy; that's to say the roadway was very busy.

However there wasn't a hold up although your sentence indicates that the intensity of traffic had forced vehicles to slow down.

(https://www.grammarly.com/handbook/grammar/articles/9/indefinite-article-with-uncountable-noun/)

Comment: Regards Ronald, and thanks. If traffic is a system of moving vehicles, then i could say : 'I was delayed by a traffic (in town A)'. The traffic can be different for each region. If this is not the case, then i presume that 'traffic' is as similar as 'mathematics' in 'His graduation was delayed by difficult mathematics.'

Comment: @Arief.an We don't use the indefinite articles *a* or *an* before uncountable nouns. For instance, you can say *water had flooded the town*  or *the water had flooded the town* (but not *a water*). Thus, you can be delayed by *a jam* but not by *a traffic* although you can be delayed by *the traffic*.

Comment: Ronald, milk is uncountable (as liquid), but if it means as packaged milk, then it cam be counted. May i refer this [Link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Heavy+traffic%2C+a+traffic+in%2C+a+milk&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHeavy%20traffic%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20traffic%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20milk%3B%2Cc0) . I presume traffic can be viewed as a unique system in a particular area.

Comment: There are contexts in which an indefinite article can precede an uncountable noun: a fog of doubt, an air of puzzlement....and so on. But the general rule holds.  *The traffic* refers to a system in a particular are: *the traffic downtown.  *Traffic* can be used in any context: *Traffic across the country/continent was affected by the weather*.